# Cannot install anything in Ionic because of Typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, npm

When I try to install anything in Ionic, I get an error which says that I don't have Typescript, and when I try to install it, it gives me the same error even though I am trying to install it.

This is the log I have:

```
1108 warn tslint@5.5.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || 

>=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev but none was 

installed.
1109 warn tsutils@2.6.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || 

>=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >= 2.4.0-dev || >= 2.5.0-dev || >= 2.6.0-dev but none 

was installed.
1110 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\HH

\Documents\ionicproject\file:cordova-common-1.1.1.tgz'
1110 verbose stack     at Error (native)
1111 verbose cwd C:\Users\HH\Documents\ionicproject
1112 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
1113 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\HH\\AppData\

\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "cordova-common@1.1.1"
1114 verbose node v6.10.2
1115 verbose npm  v5.2.0
1116 error path C:\Users\HH\Documents\ionicproject\file:cordova-common-1.1.1.tgz
1117 error code ENOENT
1118 error errno -4058
1119 error syscall stat
1120 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\HH\Documents

\ionicproject\file:cordova-common-1.1.1.tgz'
1121 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
1122 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Comment: Can you show the npm command you are using to install them?

Comment: I have tried running `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall your current typescript,

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
```

Then install tslint along with typescript

```
 npm install -g tslint typescript
```

Also clear the npm cache.

Comment: I am still getting the exact same error, when I try to install anything

Comment: Your error comes from your typescript version. Try to clean the cache, run npm install to get all dependencies and then use the provided code.

Comment: Still gives me the same error :(. First I used `npm cache clean -f` and then `npm install`